# Why doesn't my Cucumber step class open Firefox browser?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

Why doesn't my step file open Firefox browser? I have pointed the step file to the relevant geckdriver.exe

Please see my code for the step file listed below:

```
public static WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\userx\\Desktop\\CucumberFramework\\CucumberFramework\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}

@Given("^I am on the home page https://www\\.carsguide\\.com\\.auof carguide website$")
public void i_am_on_the_home_page_https_www_carsguide_com_auof_carguide_website() throws Throwable {
    driver.get("https://www.carsguide.com.au/");
}

@When("^I move to Car For Sale Menu$")
public void i_move_to_Car_For_Sale_Menu() throws Throwable {
}
```

Feature File which calls the step file:

```
Feature File
 Feature: validation of car search page

 Scenario: Searching for a new car

 Given I am on the home page https://www.carsguide.com.auof carguide website
 When I move to Car For Sale Menu
 Then I click on Search Cars
 And I select Make as "BMW"
 And I select Model as "1SERIES"
 And I select location as "Australia"
 And I select price as "$10000"
 And I click on Find My Next Car button
 Then I should see list of searched cars
 And the page title be "Bmw 1 Series Cars Under 10000 for Sale | CarsGuide"
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at steps.CarSearchSteps.i_am_on_the_home_page_https_www_carsguide_com_auof_carguide_website(CarSearchSteps.java:30)
    at ✽.Given I am on the home page https://www.carsguide.com.auof carguide website(carSearch.feature:8)
```

Answer (score 1):

your @Before method should be

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\userx\\Desktop\\CucumberFramework\\CucumberFramework\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

let me know if issues is not solved.

Comment: thanks but my Before method does specify the code you have advised.

Comment: `@Before
public void setUp() {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\userx\\Desktop\\CucumberFramework\\CucumberFramework\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}` is what Krishna believes will fix your problems. Replace your setUp() function with this one.

Comment: @Kyle Fairns thanks but isnt that the same code? a before statement followed by code which points to Ghecko driver.exe and then initialises a driver?

Comment: It's the same code as the answer above, which is why I didn't make a new answer, but it's not the same code as your question.
It's the way that it has been written, you're code initialises the driver before handing it preferences. You should hand it preferences before initialising it

Comment: you have to inter-change the lines present in your `@before` that's what @Kyle means

Comment: @Kyle Fairns i understand what you mean, im afraid dosnt fix the issue :/

Comment: @Krishna Reddy thanks for your help but dosnt resolve the problem :/

Comment: @Gbru What happens if you move the 2 lines from before method to the given method? Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I have now resolved the issue, I was importing jUnit After and Before instead of the following: import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;